# Change cell.textField.text with a datePicker

Tags: swift, uitableview, uitextfield, cell, uidatepicker

In my tableViewCell, I have a UITextField calling a UIDatePicker (code below).

My problem is : I don’t understand how to pass the date (from datePicker) in the cell.myTextField (because it appears only on the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method). Anyone could help me please ?

```
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

          //......... 

          cell.myTextField.addTarget(self, action: "showDatePicker:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.EditingDidBegin)

         //......... 
    }

    func showDatePicker(sender: UITextField) {

            var datePickerView:UIDatePicker = UIDatePicker()
            datePickerView.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerMode.Date
            sender.inputView = datePickerView

            datePickerView.addTarget(self, action: Selector("datePickerValueChanged:"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)

    }

    func datePickerValueChanged(sender:UIDatePicker) {

            var dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
            dateFormatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.NoStyle
            dateFormatter.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.FullStyle

            //dateTextField.text = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(sender.date)
            //How to load my cell.myTextField.text with the sender.date ?

    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways of do it what you want, you can combine the [`cellForRowAtIndexPath`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/cellForRowAtIndexPath:) (it's not the same as you declare as part of your `UITableViewDataSource`).

To use the above method you need to know the `indexPath` or at least the index of the row and for this you can use the [`indexPathForSelectedRow`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITableView/indexPathForSelectedRow) to get exactly the selected row an and then set the value you want like in the following way:

```
func datePickerValueChanged(sender:UIDatePicker) {

    var dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.NoStyle
    dateFormatter.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.FullStyle

    var indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()
    var cell = self.tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)
    cell.dateTextField.text = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(sender.date)
}
```

I hope this help you.

Comment: That's right, I fixed my problem with your help ! Thank you !!